# How the re-export a single entity in haskell

Tags: haskell, module

**How to re-export a single entity in haskell?**
I know modules can be re-exported, but is this also possible for a single entity (like a function)?

I've tried this example:
File: `SomeData.hs`

```hs
module SomeData where
data SomeData = SomeData
```

File: `ReExport.hs`

```hs
module ReExport ( SomeData ) where
import SomeData
```

File: `Main.hs`

```hs
import ReExport

x = SomeData -- Error on this line: Illegal term-level use of the type constructor ‘SomeData’
```

The re-export alone compiles with no problems, but when I try to use anything from it I get the error: *Illegal term-level use of the type constructor ‘SomeData’*. What exactly is `ReExport.hs` exporting in this case?

Comment: The type constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly is ReExport.hs exporting in this case?

The *type constructor*, so you can use `SomeData` as type:

```
import ReExport

x :: SomeData
x = undefined
```

If you defined a type:

```
data SomeType = SomeData
```

you are thus exporting `SomeType`.

If you want to export the data constructor as well, you use:

```
module ReExport (SomeData(SomeData)) where

import SomeData
```

and then you can thus use:

```
import ReExport

x :: SomeData
x = SomeData
```